# Unexpected output from C program

Tags: c

I'm writing a Caesar which takes in a file and an offset via STDIN, and outputs the encrypted file in STDOUT.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char encrypt(int c, char d) {
    if (c>=97&&c<=122) {
        c=c-97;
        c=c+d;
        c=c%26;
        c=c+97; 
    } else if (c>=65&&c<=90) {
        c=c-65;
        c=c+d;
        c=c%26;
        c=c+65; 
    }
    return (c);
}

void print_file(FILE* fp, char d) {
    char c;
    c = getc(fp);

    if (c==EOF) {
    printf("\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    c = encrypt(c, d);
    printf("%c", c);
    print_file(fp, d);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    char c;
    *argv[2]=*argv[2]+4; // Dunno why this makes it work but okay

    print_file(fp, *argv[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output from inputting a file with offset of 0 should print the contents of said file without any modification. Instead, the output is an offset of -4, making the input of 4 outputting the offset of 0. Moreover, any negative integer will output a fixed offset of -7.

I've added a a line of code to fix this issue, indicated by my comment. With this, the program works with positive integers, while any negative integer outputs with a fixed offset of -4.

I've tried isolating the individual functions. I cannot get this to reproduce.

Comment: Change `c` in `print_file` to `int`, otherwise it cannot be equal to `EOF`.

Comment: in c, all characters are numbers. so when you read your *argv[2], you get the ascii code of the first character that you pass in. As you have a %26, it's the same as adding the charactercode of the char you passed %26, and if this is 22, it would appear to you as if it was -4. there are two ways to solve this : 1) you want your input to be an alphabet char and then you just have to do -'a' of -'A' on it or 2) you want an actual number in which case i'd suggest you use sscanf(argv[2], "%i", &code) with code being a char input to your caesar

Comment: Side note: don't use magic numbers. Instead of `97` use `'a'`, instead of `65` use `'A'`  etc. It makes your code more readable and readability is very important.